# Page refreshes on subsequent submits

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to submit a file (image) and a quiz in a form. They both have separate buttons but the file button must be pressed first for the image path to be added to the question post data state.

However, for some reason, the page refreshes after the 2nd or 3rd image upload. This only occurs when uploading the file.

```js
// image upload form 
  <form onSubmit={handleImageUpload} encType="multipart/form-data">
              <input
                type="file"
                name="photo"
                onChange={handleFileChange}
              />
              <button type="submit" className="btn"> submit </button>
            </form>
```

```js
  const handleImageUpload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', file);
    axios.post(uploadAPI, formData).then(res => setPost({...post, image: res.data.file}));
  }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how the progress goes, so you upload three times in a row with same form or? Anyways, I think your button might be the culprit `<button type="submit" className="btn"> submit </button>`, have you tried `e.preventDefault()` there too?

Comment: @MrShumar That seemed to have fixed it thank you. Is there a reason why you need two separate ```e.preventDefault()```?

Comment: Browser will trigger Submit on form any time a button that is inside form is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swapping the `onClick` to the handle function and having the `onSubmit` call `e.preventDefault()` fixed my issue of having multiple forms on a page and random refreshes after submitting different forms in succession.

```js
<form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault()}} encType="multipart/form-data">
              <input
                type="file"
                name="photo"
                onChange={handleFileChange}
              />
              <button type="submit" className="btn" onClick={handleImageUpload}> submit </button>
</form>
```